# Mysql duplicate entry error only after restarting mysql daemon

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1062

I have a rather odd MySQL problem.

I have a table with auto incremented primary keys.

```
Primary keys are: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
Next auto increment key is 7.
```

Now I delete the last two entries.

```
Primary keys are: 1, 2, 3, 4
Next auto increment key is 7.
```

All is well.

Now, for whatever reason (perhaps an update), I restart the mysql daemon.

```
Primary keys are: 1, 2, 3, 4
Next auto increment key is 5.
```

Since this table has a foreign key I am getting a duplicate entry error.

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry
```

How can I make sure these duplicate entry errors stop happening every time I update mysql?

Update:  I just found this bug from **2003**!
http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=199

Comment: and even that bug doesn't explain your duplicate issue. I don't see any issues with recalculated PKs

Comment: I think I'm getting my terminology mixed up.  Please bear with me.  If the child table entry references the deleted parent table entry, then a 1062 error would be issued, I think.

Comment: how would you even delete a row if there are rows that refer to it?! When you delete a parent row, you get another integrity constraint violation error, not a duplicate one. Could you explain **in details** what you do to get **duplicate entry** error?

Comment: Can I explain it further? Not really.  I use Doctrine and my understanding of low-level mysql code is lacking. This question is mute anyway now that I've found out that this is the correct MySQL behaviour.  I'll have to account for it somehow in my models.

Comment: uhm, I asked already twice for you to **explain in details** what you do to get what you get. What you do? So you restart server. What else? Do you get that error right in linux shell?

Comment: And noticing about duplicate entry **is not** correct mysql behaviour. Why do you think so? The bug you found is only about autoincrement values, it should not affect duplicate entries in any way. At least that is how mysql works, still don't know what you do there. Most likely **your code** makes some inserts or updates that cause such constraint violation

Answer (score 0):

That is [how innodb calculates next autoincrement value](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html): it stores it in the memory, and on the start it just gets the `MAX(id) + 1` value.

Not sure how your second part is related to the issue. Foreign key has nothing to do with duplicates, as long as FK **may be duplicated**.

So you probably explained the issue with duplicates not well enough. At least you need to explain what actually you do to get the `duplicate entry` error